# Chrome Context Search Extension

Tags: chrome, search

When I used Firefox I had this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/context-search/

It used the same search engines already configured in Firefox.

There are similar extensions for Chrome, but they all seem to require a separate list of search engines. Are there any Chrome extensions that will reuse my Chrome search engines? Is there an extension API that gives me access to a list of installed search engines?